# InDesign — leader dots in a table (not TOC!)

Tags: adobe-indesign, tables

I'm making my first calendar (it will be an open source btw.) in Adobe InDesign CC.

Is there a way to start the dotted *Rule Above* directly after the last character?

At the moment I use large *Left Indent*, but it looks not good at all:

[image: (wrong) equal left indent]

If I set *Left Indent* to 0 it looks like this:

[image: no left indent]

Grayson's solution looks much better:

[image: Grayson's solution]

I have to disable the *Rule Above* and to insert manually (?) an additional Tab-Character in every cell of the table. After this it is possible to style leader dots via font size, color etc.

Comment: That's where it should start, given that there are no spaces after the last character.

Comment: @Joonas Maybe it should, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Command-Shift T** will snap the **"Tabs" window** above whatever text box is active. Then, for this instance, select the far left option **("Left-Justified Tab")** and click where you would like your tab to start (clicking anywhere on the gray portion above the ruler). Any lines that are tabbed will be at the point you specified (unless the characters before your tab are too long, in which case make the tab larger).

**Utilize multiple tab points to match your desired tab lengths.**

You can also precisely adjust the tab distance by typing in the "X:___" box

If you would like your tabs to have a special character in them you can add that to the "Leader:___" box

**Example:**

**1) --- INTRO**

**2) --- THESIS**

**ETC.**

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+T in Windows ;) Thanks, it works (but I have to disable the Rule Above option).

Comment: Glad I could help :D